# Where can I save preferences on Mac OS X for global access?

Tags: objective-c, macos, preference

I am developing daemon for Mac OS X that will be running under root in order to be able to perform system level operations.

At the same time I developing System Pane for the daemon - in order to configure it. I used *NSUserDefaults* to save preferences to *com.apple.systempreferences.plist* - which is fine BUT! Preferences are save for the current user only!

I was looking to write preferences to */Library/Preferences/* only to realize that I need root privileges in order to write there - which is not good (I don't want to hassle user with it and write more code in System Pane on my part).

Is there a location and an API that allows me to have preferences saved in a globally/central accessible location AND that doesn't require root privileges?

Please advise, I am quite lost at this point and if there is a better way of fulfilling above requirements please share!!!

Thank you!